# JavaScript - saving input value and cleaning the input afterwards so it can be reused without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, function, input

I'm new to JavaScript so forgive my ignorance in this case.
I'm trying to create a script that makes it possible for the user to give in a number in an input field. This number(1) needs to be stored somehow after the user hits "Enter" on the keyboard and the input field should become empty again for the user to give in a new number(2). After hitting a second time on the "Enter" button the script needs to calculate automatically how much number(1) + number(2) is together. And this needs to be possible for an undefined amount of numbers..

So far i figured it might be useful to add those numbers to an array, since i have no idea how to solve this task with the use of just a function.

I managed to get the field empty again and the number stored and printed.

My question is, how do i calculate the results? Because for now it just prints the array made in one big line of numbers instead. I can't seem to find out how to calculate it all.. Maybe you guys know a way to do it?

Another question i have, is this possible at all without using an array?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Give me a number:</p>
<p id="inputNumber"><input type="number" id="new" onchange="submit()"></p>
<p>Your input:</p>
<p id="input"></p>
<p>Results of calculations:</p>
<p id="results"></p>


<script>
// Create an Array to hold the numbers
var numbers = [];

// Create a Function to get the numbers and store them in the Array 'numbers'
function submit() {

    // Get the user input
    var newNumber = document.getElementById("new");

    // Adding it to the array number
    numbers.push(newNumber.value);

    // Make input field empty for re-use
    document.getElementById("inputNumber").innerHTML = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"new\" onchange=\"submit()\">";

    // Create a for loop that loops through the Array 'numbers'
    var showInput = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       showInput += numbers[i] + "<br>";
       }

    // Showing the input back to user
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = showInput;

    // Create a for loop that loops through the Array 'numbers'
    var showResults = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       showResults += numbers[i];
       }
    // Showing the results of the calculation
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = showResults;
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** You've changed your question after the fact. The reason your sum displays as a long line of numbers is that the values in the `numbers` array are strings, and if you combine them with the `+` operator, the result will be a concatenated string. You need to start `showResults` off at 0 and convert each member of the array to a number (or convert them to numbers when adding them to the array).

**Explanation from original answer:**

The problem you're having is that you are overwriting the `showInput` and `showResults` variables on every iteration of the loop instead of adding to them. The `+=` operator will help with this.

Also, there's a better way to clear the input that doesn't involve replacing its whole HTML. See below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Give me a number:</p>
  <p id="inputNumber">
    <input type="number" id="new" onchange="submit()">
  </p>
  <p>Your input:</p>
  <p id="input"></p>
  <p>Results of calculations:</p>
  <p id="results"></p>


  <script>
    // Create an Array to hold the numbers
    var numbers = [];

     // Create a Function to get the numbers and store them in the Array 'numbers'
    function submit() {

      // Get the user input
      var newNumber = document.getElementById("new");

      var showInput = '';
      var showResults = 0;

      // Adding it to the array number
      numbers.push(newNumber.value);

      // Make input field empty for re-use
      newNumber.value = '';

      // Create a for loop that loops through the Array 'numbers'
      for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        showInput += numbers[i] + "<br>";
      }

      // Showing the input back to user
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = showInput;

      // Create a for loop that loops through the Array 'numbers'
      for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        showResults += Number(numbers[i]);
      }
      // Showing the results of the calculation
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = showResults;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

There are also fancy ways to do the concatenation and addition without explicitly using loops. Just as an addendum, here's how you can do that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Give me a number:</p>
  <p id="inputNumber">
    <input type="number" id="new" onchange="submit()">
  </p>
  <p>Your input:</p>
  <p id="input"></p>
  <p>Results of calculations:</p>
  <p id="results"></p>


  <script>
    // Create an Array to hold the numbers
    var numbers = [];

     // Create a Function to get the numbers and store them in the Array 'numbers'
    function submit() {

      // Get the user input
      var newNumber = document.getElementById("new");

      // Adding it to the array number
      numbers.push(newNumber.value);

      // Make input field empty for re-use
      newNumber.value = '';

      // Create a for loop that loops through the Array 'numbers'
      var showInput = numbers.map(function (n) {
          return n + '<br>';
      }).join('');

      // Showing the input back to user
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = showInput;

      // Create a for loop that loops through the Array 'numbers'
      var showResults = numbers.reduce(function (l, r) {
          return l + Number(r);
      }, 0);

      // Showing the results of the calculation
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = showResults;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And as requested, here's how to do this without storing the values in an array:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Give me a number:</p>
  <p id="inputNumber">
    <input type="number" id="new" onchange="submit()">
  </p>
  <p>Your input:</p>
  <p id="input"></p>
  <p>Results of calculations:</p>
  <p id="results">0</p>


  <script>
     // Create a Function to get the numbers and store them in the Array 'numbers'
    function submit() {
      // Get the user input
      var newNumber = document.getElementById("new");

      // store the value to a variable
      var newValue = newNumber.value;

      // Make input field empty for re-use
      newNumber.value = '';

      // append to the list of entered values
      var inputs = document.getElementById("input");
      inputs.innerHTML += newValue + '<br>';

      // Update the total
      var results = document.getElementById("results");
      results.textContent = Number(results.textContent) + Number(newValue);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this all work without using an Array?

Comment: @HerMan Yes, certainly it's possible, but why don't you want to use an array?

Comment: I want to learn how to do it all possible ways for future use! :)

Answer (score 0):

First I think it would be easier to clear your input like this

```
// Make input field empty for re-use
newNumber.value='';
```

and to get the summation you can loop through the array like this

```
var total = 0;
for(var i in numbers )
{
     total += numbers[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line....

```
// Make input field empty for re-use
    document.getElementById("inputNumber").innerHTML = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"new\" onchange=\"submit()\">";
```

to this.

```
// Make input field empty for re-use
    document.getElementById("new").value= "";
```

Comment: or to: newNumber.value = '';
Thanks anyway! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was performing with addition calculation.With end of the answer

> Without array.

Its will save the input until the page refresh

**update**

```js
function submit() {
  //get the value from input string
       var newNumber = document.getElementById("new").value;
  //after hit enter clear the input field       
  document.getElementById("new").value ="";
  //its will place the value one by one  see the `+` before `=` it  will show the values
         document.getElementById("input").innerHTML += newNumber + "<br>";
  // this `store` variable get value from result.   
  var store = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML;
  //first time the result is a empty so apply with if condition.The nxt time click its load previous result value.is not ah empty so direct with calculation
  if(store =="")
  //its a empty store the variable is `0`
  {store='0';} 
  
  //its willl adding the previous result and newvalue(calculation)
 document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=Math.floor(parseFloat(newNumber)+parseFloat(store));
   
    
    }
```

```html
<p>Give me a number:</p>
    <p id="inputNumber"><input type="number" id="new" onchange="submit()"></p>
    <p>Your input:</p>
    <p id="input"></p>
    <p>Results of calculations:</p>
    <p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a mil! Just one question concerning your code.. Where does it calculate and where does it store the number? I see it happens, just don't follow the code so much :))

Comment: @Her Man Are you little confusion with accepting answer?